# Custom SilverStripe ModelAdmin does not show up

Tags: silverstripe

I have a site running on SilverStripe (CMS version 3.1) with a custom module including a `ModelAdmin` class. It shows up just fine in development (as seen below, right under Pages) but *not* in production. The module is not registering at all in production, there's no way to access the forms via the URL in production.

[image: The module is there!]

The code on the server is up to date. Subsequent changes are, in fact, working as expected.

I've previously attempted dumping the SilverStripe cache to no avail. What kind of issues could be causing this, and where would I begin to properly debug this?

---

Edit: the module doesn't seem to show up for *anyone* regardless of user type, even the default admin.

Comment: Possibly it's a permissions problem. Make sure you've given permissions for your custom Admin to appropriate groups in Security->Groups->(GroupName)->Permissions.

Comment: If it shows up for Admin user but not for editors, it's a permission problem as stated above. Did you run dev/build and flush on the production server after updating the code? Did you install all modules using composer on the prod machine? Any errors in your logs?

Comment: Are you using `canView()` in your ModelAdmin at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you flush your cache in the admin section with `http://www.example.com/admin/?flush=all`

Comment: Didn't realize this was distinct from the `/dev/build/?flush=all`. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to flush one time too often :(

Comment: Yeah. If in doubt, flush.